# bootstrap modal cookie not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cookies, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to show a bootstrap modal when the page loads (only 1 time) and set a cookie for 7 days. But something prevents the modal to show up. If I don't use the jquery-cookie the modal turns up. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($.cookie('pop') == null) {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    $.cookie('pop', '7');
  }
});
```

```
<div class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `alert($.cookie('pop'));` before if statement. If something shows up in alert box then the modal will not show as $.cookie('pop') == null will be false and so the if statement will not execute `$('#myModal').modal('show');`

Answer (score 0):

Adding alert($.cookie('pop')); doesn't do anything different. Still no popup or other message.